# How to create a cohort query with Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-science

I'm trying to measure a specific user behaviour of users of every day after they sign up to a given service.

This is an example of a table I'd like to create

[image]

Where the date (x axis) is the day the user joined and the days after joining is `user.created_at + x days`.

The values are the % of the users of that cohort who undertook a specific action on x days after they signed up.

Is there a way to generate this purely with Postgresql?

Comment: Do you want it explicitly for these dates (sept 28 - oct 3) -> fixed columns? Or you want it 5 days into the past no matter what date currently is -> columns are dynamic? Do you want it for more than 5 days?

Comment: What's the table structure? Anyway, it seems you need a "pivot" query. I think they are called "crosstab" in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Comment: It would be for the previous 7 or 28 days (for example). As for the table structure, I have a `users` table and a `posts` table each with `created_at` dates. The query is to see what % of users created a post x days after sign up.